# How do I echo the date into an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I echo the date in a PHP array?

Normally, I would use `<?php echo $date("Y")?>`, however I don't know how to put this into an array.

Is this possible or is this practice not recommended?

```
<?php
    $array= array("THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ECHO THE CURRENT DATE", "Two", "Three"); 
    echo . $array[0] . ", " . $cars[1] . " and " . $cars[2] . ".";
?>
```

Comment: Have you learnt about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)? If so, then look through [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: How about `$array = array(date('Y'), 'Two', 'Three');`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an array and want to insert at a specific location do:

```
$array= array("Object to be replaced", "Two", "Three");
$array[0] = Date('Y');
// print_r($array) will output [0] => "theDate"; [1] "Two"; [2] "three"
```

If you want to push it to the end of the array do:

```
array_`push($array,` Date('Y');
// print_r($array) will output [0] => "Object to be replaced"; [1] "Two"; [2] "three"; [3] "theDate";
```